# JetBrains Gateway never finishes loading

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-gateway

I'm trying to use JetBrains Gateway to work on a project and it was working for several weeks, but today the IDE has never loaded the code, despite saying that it's connected.  Instead it shows a red ping warning.  I've tried connecting to the server from several different internet connections.  SSH seems to be working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it working by restarting the Linux machine with `sudo systemctl start reboot.target`.  I'm still seeing the ping error but the code is at least loading in the Gateway IDE.